# How can I create the following graph in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can I create a simple graph with different shapes? I am not sure how to do this image.

[image: A tree containing a bunch of nodes and large triangles containing nodes within them].

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you add your trial code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all honesty, I don't understand what you want to draw. I'm just giving to you as an example... using a tool online to generate a `TikZ` code, called [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor), for beginner in LaTeX (and `TikZ`) without MWE (minimal working code example). The manual of TikZ is to the link:

> http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}


\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw   (285,38) .. controls (285,28.06) and (293.06,20) .. (303,20) .. controls (312.94,20) and (321,28.06) .. (321,38) .. controls (321,47.94) and (312.94,56) .. (303,56) .. controls (293.06,56) and (285,47.94) .. (285,38) -- cycle ;
\draw    (303,56) -- (302.5,97) ;
\draw   (284.5,115) .. controls (284.5,105.06) and (292.56,97) .. (302.5,97) .. controls (312.44,97) and (320.5,105.06) .. (320.5,115) .. controls (320.5,124.94) and (312.44,133) .. (302.5,133) .. controls (292.56,133) and (284.5,124.94) .. (284.5,115) -- cycle ;
\draw    (284.5,115) -- (231.25,150) ;
\draw    (320.5,115) -- (370.25,150) ;
\draw   (231.25,150) -- (298.3,271) -- (164.2,271) -- cycle ;
\draw   (370.25,150) -- (437.47,271.3) -- (303.03,271.3) -- cycle ;
\draw    (209.86,190.67) -- (221.07,217.2) ;
\draw    (392.36,190.17) -- (375.11,215.33) ;
\draw   (203.07,235.2) .. controls (203.07,225.26) and (211.13,217.2) .. (221.07,217.2) .. controls (231.01,217.2) and (239.07,225.26) .. (239.07,235.2) .. controls (239.07,245.14) and (231.01,253.2) .. (221.07,253.2) .. controls (211.13,253.2) and (203.07,245.14) .. (203.07,235.2) -- cycle ;
\draw   (357.11,233.33) .. controls (357.11,223.39) and (365.17,215.33) .. (375.11,215.33) .. controls (385.05,215.33) and (393.11,223.39) .. (393.11,233.33) .. controls (393.11,243.27) and (385.05,251.33) .. (375.11,251.33) .. controls (365.17,251.33) and (357.11,243.27) .. (357.11,233.33) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I would like that using flexible graph theoretical instructions.I can make simple graphs that contain only one type of nodes but I can't create a graph that contains both large triangles and circles which can be connected within the large triangles